# FoxPro Работа со строкой как с датой (преобразование)

Tags: delphi, база-данных

В таблице FoxPro хранятся даты в виде ДД.ММ.ГГГГ. При подключении в Delphi через TADOQuery, выбираются даты в формате ММ.ДД.ГГГГ. Как выбрать из такой таблицы даты в определенном промежутке?

`CTOD(str)` - преобразует из формата ММ.ДД.ГГГГ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Сделал внешнюю процедуру и использовал её для конвертирования строки формата DD.MM.YYYY в дату. Для решения задачи создал файл tss.prg в директории с БД:

```
PROCEDURE tss(paramUserName AS Character)
RETURN CTOD(substr(paramUserName,4,1)+substr(paramUserName,5,1)+'.'+substr(paramUserName,1,1)+substr(paramUserName,2,1)+'.'+substr(paramUserName,7,1)+substr(paramUserName,8,1)+substr(paramUserName,9,1)+substr(paramUserName,10,1))
```

После этого при обращении к БД в теле запроса можно использовать функцию tss(dateField), которая возвращает дату.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо привести SQL-запрос к виду, который ожидает база, то есть к формату DD/MM/YYYY. Изначально хорошо бы попробовать повыполнять такие запросы непосредственно в менедреже управления FoxPro (я не знаю как он называется) чтобы увидеть как база реагирует.

В Delphi приведение форматов делается при помощи записи `var: fs: TFormatSettings`:

```
fs.ShortDateFormat := 'dd mmm yyyy';
fs.DateSeparator := '/'; // или '.', или ':'
```

После того как даты приведены к корректному виду, можно создать запрос с оператором `BETWEEN`:

`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Created BETWEEN aDate AND bDate`

В разных диалектах SQL синтаксис может немного различаться, но в целом эта конструкция должна работать.

Comment: Это не поможет. В таблице даты хранятся строкой, в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ. К примеру, CTOD('13.02.2008') вернет дату "30 декабря 1899 года", по всей видимости, из-за того, что триннадцатого месяца нет. В итоге - какую бы Вы не подставили дату, сравнивать её программа будет с американским форматом (MDY). Я не могу найти где его изменить или указать в запросе, что будем использовать другой.

Comment: Даты хранятся строками? Ужасно... Это нарушение одного из базовых концептов хранения данных, ради которого, собственно, и были придуманы типы данных. Я бы убедительно советовал для начала создать в таблице поле типа datetime и сконвертировать в него строковые "даты". Ибо работа с датами, представленными в виде строк – это танцы с бубнами.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но конвертация - это в крайнем случае. БД не моя, мне надо только периодически из нее забирать данные.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, возможно использование запроса с параметрами:

```
Query.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateField BETWEEN :Date1 AND :Date2');
Query.Parameters.CreateParameter('Date1', ftDateTime, pdInput, 0, Date1);
Query.Parameters.CreateParameter('Date2', ftDateTime, pdInput, 0, Date2);
```

или если типы параметров параметры уже были созданы и описаны в инспекторе объектов, то:

```
Query.Parameters.ParamByName('Date1').Value := Date1;
Query.Parameters.ParamByName('Date2').Value := Date2;
```

Приведение даты в совместимый вид будет произведено автоматически.

Comment: Проблема в самом поле DateField. Выборка не будет соответствовать ожиданиям. Допустим, подставляемую дату удалось привести к требуемому виду! Сравнивать-то её драйвер будет со строкой, из которой, при текущих настройках, получить ДАТУ не получается!

Comment: При передаче значения через параметр все преобразования производятся на уровне драйвера базы данных. На самом деле происходит обращение через интерфейсы ADO. В них передается текст запроса с параметрами и список параметров, в которых описывается тип данных, размер, значение и т.д. То есть преобразование в запросе в строку не производится. В модулях ADODB.pas и ADOInt.pas это хорошо видно.